# Create object looping through enum values which will have keys from enum

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface

I have an Enum like that:

```js
export enum Language {
  PL = 'pl',
  EN = 'en',
}
```

And now I want to create object with following structure:

```js
{
  pl: { name: '' },
  en: { name: '' }
}
```

So I have created a function like that:

```js
const createInitialValues = () => {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    Object.values(Language).map(lang => {
      return {
        [lang]: { name: '' },
      };
    })
  );
};
```

And I want to assign it to the following object:

```js
export const categoryFormInitialValues: ICategoryForm = {
  name: '',
  language: '',
  translations: createInitialValues(),
};
```

But I'm getting typescript error under translations property:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: { name: string; }; }[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ pl: ITranslatedCategoryForm; en: ITranslatedCategoryForm; }': pl, ents(2739)
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: where is `ICategoryForm` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Your big problem is that you're passing [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) a single parameter containing an array of objects, which is not how `Object.assign()` works.  You need to pass multiple parameters.  The easiest way is to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax):

```
const createInitialValues = () => {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...Object.values(Language).map(lang => { // <-- spread here
      return {
        [lang]: { name: '' },
      };
    })
  );
};
```

That will fix your problem at runtime at least.

Unfortunately for type safety, TypeScript doesn't give strong typings to variadic `Object.assign()` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#28323](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28323) for more info) and so calling it like above will result in an output type of `any`, [the "type" corresponding to turning off type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any).

Even if you could fix that, the compiler doesn't currently understand how to strongly type computed properties as in `{[lang]: {name:''}}` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) for details), so you'd end up with an output type that was wider than you want, like `{[k: string]: {name: ''}}`.  That's better than `any`, but still not great.

And even if you could fix *that*, the compiler wouldn't be sure that the output had *all* the properties from `Language`, since there's no easy way to say that something like `Object.values()` produces an *exhaustive* array.  All it knows is that it produces `Language[]`, which (for all the compiler knows) could be just `["en"]` without `"pl"`.  So you'd probably end up with something like `Partial<Record<Language, {name: ""}>>` instead of the desired `Record<Language, {name: ""}>`.

Instead of trying to fix all of those issues just for this one function, I'd be inclined to face the fact that I'm smarter than the compiler in this instance and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to get the desired output type of `Record<Language, {name: ""}>`:

```
const createInitialValues = () => {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...Object.values(Language).map(lang => {
      return {
        [lang]: { name: '' },
      };
    })
  ) as Record<Language, { name: "" }>;
};
```

Which should hopefully make your code start working both at runtime and in TypeScript.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMghiA5mOjhQN4CgpQAoxQC8UA5AA4A2pANDlAKIByxZotWAvllgMYD2IAM4AXKLwBOwOCOABJEAEsRiuJQBqasMCGsAFAEpiAPkz0pIsBJBQA8gCMAVsF4iAdHCFDFiEHvq4GJx0uLhu4Q7Orm4Ablo6evBIKGgGbhBw5HqUCIgmZqGhFlY22IWFANo5SAC6AFyYUCBwEMANpKRQwQGhnADcPZwG9EaeUABKLvwSACYAPEnIqMA0jc2tDQBEm13GA-08iiCyEgBmcLzoACoAFkd5ZVBUDRhNLW1knd24oC9vG58ulweAJhGIRHckA1bvdWJJpLIFMpVBp4kJDANQUJ+JRgG5KPxEHoIfcDEA)